# DataSet within class is not being refreshed asynchronously?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, datatable, async-await

### **tl;dr**

Sorry if the question title is misleading; it's a work in progress as I try to get to the root of the issue.

I am making a `.Single( Row => ... ... )` call against the `.AsEnumerable( )` extension of a `DataTable` that is throwing an exception. Looking into the table, there are two rows present which is impossible because, looking at the SOURCE table (the one on the data base from which this `DataTable` SHOULD be populated), I am seeing only one of these rows.

In an effort to narrow down the problem, I am assigning a primary key to the table, which is now generating an impossible exception telling me the primary key already exists within the table, which should not be the case as the table should have been ***just*** created.

Why is this happening?

### Did Read:

I'd hoped that in the course of forming this question that I would have come upon the solution in one of those "talking with a colleague/cardboard cutout *AHA*" moments; not so much.

There is quite a bit of code going on here, and I will explain as best as I am able what I am trying to accomplish (I also apologize, as I do not know precisely what all of the proper terminology is for what I am trying to describe).

I am working on a project component which will effectively act as an intermediary between an online data base and a desktop application. As portability is the primary concern, I am making the component primarily event driven.

It is also the case that there are many things going on which must run concurrently; as such, I have endeavoured to implement this component asynchronously (`async` and `await`).

The program depends on a static class (which I have constructed) which contains a number of `DataTables`.

Before I post my code, I should say that my initial suspicion is that multiple asynchronous tasks running in parallel are... "crashing into each other" somehow. I do not know if this is the case for certain, though.

I will start from where I believe the source of the problem is and work my way down through the stack. I will attempt to do this in a depth-first manner for the sake of brevity. More can be added later if necessary.

Before I get into the trace, I want to post the method which is my primary suspect:

```
/// <summary>
/// Asynchronously read tables for this SqlLibAsync instance.
/// </summary>
public async Task ReadTables( ) {
    this.DS = new DataSet( );
    using ( MySqlConnection MSQCon = new MySqlConnection( this.ConnectionString ) ) {
        await MSQCon.OpenAsync( );
        try {
            foreach ( MySqlDataAdapter Adapter in this.Adapters ) {
                Adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = MSQCon;
                await Adapter.FillAsync( this.DS, 
                     Adapter.TableMappings.Cast<DataTableMapping>()
                         .First( )
                         .SourceTable 
                ); //In fact, could the troubles be originating from this .Cast<>() call?
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.Report( );
        }
        await MSQCon.CloseAsync( );
    }
    if ( this.DS.Tables.Count == 0 )
        await this.ReadTables( );
}
```

This method has given me quite a bit of trouble and has gone through several iterations. In the past I was receiving an exception informing me that a connection attempt had been made while a `DataReader` was already accessing the connection, or something, which I believe was because I was using multiple instances of this class to do work asynchronously, and in am improper fashion for such work (basically, multiple connections from a single computer to the same database), so I went with this route which seems to have dealt with that issue, but now I am getting this new issue. I believe that, for some reason, parallel asynchronous tasks and this method are not getting along, but I lack the know as to why.

The start of the tree to get to this methods use, in the context of which I am having my problems, is here:

```
public static async Task Start( ) {
    /*I have omitted code that appears to be working properly. #1*/
    bool
        Pending = true;
    /*Another Code Omission. #2*/           
    while ( Session.Instance.Status != SessionStatus.FINALIZED && Session.UserID != 0 ) {
        List<Task> TList = new List<Task>();
        TList.Add( Session.Instance.PlayerCheck( ) );
        switch ( Session.Instance.Status ) {
            case SessionStatus.PENDING:
                if ( Pending ) {
                    Pending = false;
                    TList.Add( Session.OnSessionReport( ) );
                }
                break;      
        }
        /*Another Omission #3*/
        await Task.WhenAll( TList );
    }
    /*More omitted code*/
}
```

We will start with `Session.Instance`

```
private static Session _Instance; // Private static reference to a session.

/// <summary>
/// Static reference to instance of the Session.
/// </summary>
public static Session Instance { get { return Session._Instance; } }
```

Next we have the`Status` property of the `Session` class:

```
private SessionStatus Status { //Retrieve fresh session status.
    get {
        switch ( this.FreshRow.Field<string>( "status" ) ) {
            /*Translates the incoming string into an enum. #4*/
        }
    }
}
```

The `Status` property references the FreshRow property:

```
private DataRow FreshRow { //Retrieves datarow from which fresh session information can be extracted. (Status, BuzzedInUser, etc).
    get {
        if ( this.SessionID == 0 )
            throw new ObjectDisposedException( "Session", "Illegal attempt to access disposed Session object." );
        return QatiTables.GameSessions.Fresh.AsEnumerable( ).Single( Row => Row.Field<UInt32>( "game_session_id" ).Equals( this.SessionID ) );
    }
    /*Session.SessionID is a simple property with a getter and a private setter.*/
}
```

From here we have the `QatiTables.GameSessions` property:

```
public static SqlTableAsync GameSessions {
    get {
        return QatiTables.Tables[1] ?? ( QatiTables.Tables[1] = new SqlTableAsync(
            "QAndATimeServer.txt",
            "game_sessions",
            "created_by = @param_val_0", //We have to grab all of these every time because the row status may change mid-game and we would lose it.
            new object[ ] { QatiTables.Users.Fresh.AsEnumerable( ).Single( ).Field<UInt32>( "user_id" ) } ) );
    }
    /*The referenced QatiTables.Tables[] is an array of SqlTableAsync objects.*/
}
```

This property makes use of the `SqlTableAsync` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [FILTER]
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ServerFile">FTP File containing database connection data.</param>
/// <param name="TableName">Table to retrieve.</param>
/// <param name="Filter">Query Filter</param>
/// <param name="Parameters">Parameters on which to filter.</param>
public SqlTableAsync( string ServerFile, string TableName, string Filter, object[ ] Parameters ) {
    this.TableLib = new SqlLibAsync( "QAndATimeServer.txt" );
    try { this.TableLib.GetTable( TableName, Filter, Parameters ).Wait( ); } catch ( Exception e ) {
        e.Report( );
        /*Report is a custom extension method for exceptions. #5*/
    }
    this.TableName = TableName;
}
```

From within this constructor we have the `SqlLibAsync` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Initialize a new SqlLib
/// </summary>
/// <param name="DatabaseConnection">Text File from which to read database connection parameters on File Server</param>
public SqlLibAsync( string DatabaseConnection ) { this.ConnectionFile = DatabaseConnection; }

/// <summary>
/// Set FTP file from which to read connection data.
/// </summary>
private string ConnectionFile {
    set {
         /*This populates local variables with information from a file read 
         directly from an FTP server. As such, I have omitted this code as 
         it functions as it should, and also as it contains some sensitive 
         bits of information.*/
    }
}
```

We've reached the end of our first branch! Hooray!

Going back up, our next referenced method is the `SqlLibAsync.GetTable( )` method:

```
/// <summary>
/// SELECT * FROM [TABLE] WHERE [FILTER]
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Table">Table Name</param>
/// <param name="Filter">Query Filter</param>
/// <param name="Parameters">Object of parameters with which to populate filter.</param>
public async Task GetTable( string Table, string Filter, object[ ] Parameters ) {
    await this.GetTables( new string[ ] { Table }, new string[ ] { Filter }, new object[ ][ ] { Parameters } );
}
```

This method makes reference to the SqlLibAsync.GetTables( ... ) method:

```
/// <summary>
/// Return Multiple Tables from a Data Set.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="Tables">Tables for which to query</param>
public async Task GetTables( string[ ] Tables, string[ ] Filters, object[ ][ ] Parameters ) {
    this.Adapters = new MySqlDataAdapter[Tables.Length];
    int FilterIndex;
    object[ ] ParameterSet = null;
    string Query = null, Filter = null;
    foreach ( string Table in Tables ) {
        FilterIndex = Tables.ToList( ).IndexOf( Table );
        Filter = Filters[FilterIndex];
        ParameterSet = Parameters[FilterIndex];
        Query = "SELECT * FROM " + Table + " WHERE ";
        if ( string.IsNullOrEmpty( Filter ) )
            Query += "1;";
        else
            Query += Filter + ";";
        MySqlDataAdapter Adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter( new MySqlCommand( Query ) { CommandType = CommandType.Text } );
        if ( ParameterSet != null )
            for ( int x = 0; x < ParameterSet.Length; x++ )
                Adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@param_val_" + x, ParameterSet[x] );
        Adapter.TableMappings.Add( Table, Table );
        this.Adapters[Tables.ToList( ).IndexOf( Table )] = Adapter;
    }
    await this.ReadTables( );
}
```

This method makes use of the first described `SqlLibAsync.ReadTables` method.
This brings us to the end of our second branch.

We now rescind to the `QatiTables.GameSessions` property reference to the `QatiTables.Users` property:

```
public static SqlTableAsync Users {
    get {
        return QatiTables.Tables[0] ?? ( QatiTables.Tables[0] = new SqlTableAsync(
            "QAndATimeServer.txt",
            "users",
            "last_ip_address = @param_val_0 AND role IN (@param_val_1, @param_val_2) AND is_login = @param_val_3",
            new object[ ] { Methods.IPAddress, "admin", "entertainer", 1 } ) );
    }
}
```

This property references a static `Methods.IPAddress` property, which I will omit as I feel the context in which it is used defines it sufficiently.

This property also makes use of the `SqlTablesAsync` class, it's methods and properties, which are described previously.

This property also brings us to the end of another branch.

The next branch is the `Fresh` property of the `SqlTableAsync` class, referenced in the `FreshRow` property of the `Session` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get fresh table.
/// </summary>
public DataTable Fresh { get {
    try {
        this.TableLib.ReadTables( ).Wait( );
        return this.TableLib.Tables[this.TableName];
    } catch ( Exception EX ) {
        EX.Report( );
        return null;
    }
} }
```

This makes reference to the `TableLib` variable; a local `SqlTableAsync` class object. It also makes reference to the `ReadTables` method of that class (described previously), as well as the `Tables` property of that class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get this SqlLibs table set.
/// </summary>
public DataTableCollection Tables { get { return this.DS.Tables; } }
```

This property makes reference to the class `DS` variable, a `DataSet` described in previous methods.

And finally, we've reached the end of our first major branch, the `Status` property of the `Session` class, and all of it's related classes, properties, methods and functions, which brings us to our next major branch: the UserID property of the Session class:

```
private static UInt32 UserID { // Static Logged In UserID
    get {
        IEnumerable<DataRow> Users = QatiTables.Users.Fresh.AsEnumerable( ); //To avoid multiple unnecessary queries.
        return Users.Count( ) == 1 ? Users.Single( ).Field<UInt32>( "User_ID" ) : 0;
    }
}
```

Fortunately, this branch ends quickly as it references the `Users` property of the `QatiTables` class, which has been described in detail above. This ends the start of our initial While loop in the Start method above.

The next branch is the `PlayerCheck` method of the `Session` class. Before we get into the meat of the method, the method itself is designed to run frequent checks against the database and inform the program when players join and leave the game. This method may also be considered my second most likely suspect as to the cause of my problem.

```
private async Task PlayerCheck( ) {
    List<Task> TList = new List<Task>( );
    IEnumerable<Player> Candidates = ( await QatiTables.Players.FreshAsync( ) ).AsEnumerable(
        ).Select<DataRow, Player>( Row => new Player( Row.Field<UInt32>( "participant_id" ), this.SessionID ) );
    Candidates.Where( P =>
        !( PlayerStatus.BLOCKED | PlayerStatus.KICKED | PlayerStatus.QUIT | PlayerStatus.LOGOFF ).HasFlag( P.Status ) &&
        !this._Players.Contains( P ) ).ToList( ).ForEach( P => {
            this._Players.Add( P );
            TList.Add( Session.OnPlayerJoined( P ) );
        } );
    Candidates.Where( P =>
        ( PlayerStatus.BLOCKED | PlayerStatus.KICKED | PlayerStatus.QUIT | PlayerStatus.LOGOFF ).HasFlag( P.Status ) &&
        this._Players.Contains( P ) ).ToList( ).ForEach( P => {
            this._Players.Remove( P );
            TList.Add( Session.OnPlayerLeft( P ) );
        } );
    await Task.WhenAll( TList );
}
```

Within this method we have first referenced the `Players` property of the `QatiTables` class:

```
public static SqlTableAsync Players {
    get {
        try {
            return QatiTables.Tables[7] ?? ( QatiTables.Tables[7] = new SqlTableAsync(
                "QAndATimeServer.txt",
                "session_participants",
                "session_id = @param_val_0",
                new object[ ] { QatiTables.GameSessions.Fresh.AsEnumerable( ).Where( Row =>
                !QatiTables.GameEndedFilter.Contains( Row.Field<string>( "status" ) )
                ).Single( ).Field<UInt32>( "game_session_id" ) } ) );
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.Report( );
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This method references the `SqlTableAsync` class with which we are by now familiar. Going back up, we see the `Session.PlayerCheck` method referencing the `FresAsync( )` function of the `SqlTableAsync` class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Get fresh table asynchronously.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>Refreshed Table</returns>
public async Task<DataTable> FreshAsync( ) {
    await this.TableLib.ReadTables( );
    return this.TableLib.Tables[this.TableName];
}
```

This method is identical to the `Fresh` property, only that it has been tagged with the `async` keyword.

Moving back to the `Session.PlayerCheck` method, we see the method selecting the `QatiTables.Players` rows into a collection of `Player` class objects using the `session_participant_id` of the data row and the `SessionID` of the session class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Create new Player object.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="PlayerID">Player ID</param>
/// <param name="SessionID">ID of session player is in.</param>
public Player( UInt32 PlayerID, UInt32 SessionID ) {
    this.PlayerID = PlayerID;
    this.SessionID = SessionID;
}
```

Going back up, the part filters our `Candidates` `IEnumerable<Player>` on the criteria that they are present and active within the current game (Not `BLOCKED`, `KICKED`, etc) AND that they are not presently accounted for within our current session. This makes use of the `Player.Status` property...

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get player status.
    /// </summary>
    public PlayerStatus Status {
        get {
            switch ( this.FreshRow.Field<string>( "status" ) ) {
                /*Converts the string into an appropriate player status*/
            }
        }
    }
```

...which makes use of the `Player.FreshRow` property...

```
private DataRow FreshRow {//Retrieve a fresh row from which data may be extracted.
    get {
        if ( this.PlayerID == 0 || this.SessionID == 0 )
            throw new ObjectDisposedException( "Player", "Illegal attempt to access disposed Player object." );
        try {
            return QatiTables.Players.Fresh.AsEnumerable( ).Single( Row =>
                Row.Field<UInt32>( "participant_id" ).Equals( this.PlayerID ) &&
                Row.Field<UInt32>( "session_id" ).Equals( this.SessionID ) );
        } catch ( Exception EX ) {
            EX.Report( );
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

... which is actually from where the exception is coming!!! This is where the `Single( Row => ... ... )` is throwing an exception, saying that there exists TWO ROWS within this data table that match the provided criteria!!! WE MADE IT!!! This property also makes reference to the `Fresh` property of the  `Players` property of the `QatiTables` class, an `SqlTableAsync` class object with which we should by now be familiar.

**PHEW!!!**

For the sake of being complete, the referenced `_Players` value of the `Session` class is simply a list of `Player` class objects, and we also have referenced the static `Session.OnPlayerJoined( Player )` method:

```
private static async Task OnPlayerJoined( Player P ) {
    if ( Session._PlayerJoined != null )
        await Task.Run( ( ) => Session._PlayerJoined( Session.Instance, P ) );
}
```

This method invokes an event if it exists in an asynchronous fashion. Nothing fancy going on here, at least, I don't think so.

Thus ends the first filter of the `Candidates` `IEnumerable`. The next filter does something very similar; it filters players on the criteria that they HAVE been removed from the game (`BLOCKED`, `KICKED`, etc), AND are presently accounted for, that is, within the list of players for this session.

One other piece of information: The Player class implements the `IEquatable<Player>` interface in the following fashion:

```
public class Player : IDisposable, IEquatable<Player> {
    /*Code omitted*/
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if this player is equivalent to another player.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="other">Player with which to compare this player.</param>
    /// <returns>PlayerID.Equals(other.PlayerID)</returns>
    public bool Equals( Player other ) { return this.PlayerID.Equals( other.PlayerID ); }
}
```

This takes us to the end of the branch within the `PlayerCheck` method, and back up into the `Start` method. The only other branch left in the tree is the `Session.OnSessionReport( )` method which, for all intents and purposes, is identical to the `OnPlayerJoined` and `OnPlayerLeft` methods: It calls an event handler asynchronously, if the event handler is not null.

Now that we've traversed the tree, the problem I am having (as described above in brief) is this: When calling the `Player.Status` property, the `Single( Row => ... ... )` method within the `FreshRow` property of that class is throwing an exception, telling me that there were multiple rows that match the criteria on which I am filtering. This is absurd because I am filtering on the `PRIMARY KEY` of that data table to get that row. Yet, somehow, when I managed to look at that table, sure enough, there were two, yes two, rows that matched the provided criteria. Yet, when I looked at the table on the data base from which this table gets its information, I find only one.

***Why is this happening?***

### EDIT

In an effort to narrow down the issue, I am going to implement into the `SqlTableAsync` and `SqlLibAsync` classes support for adding primary keys. This should result in an exception when the `DataTable` is populated with multiple rows containing the same primary key.

To that end I have changed the `Fresh` property and the `FreshAsync` methods of the `SqlTableAsync` class to the following:

```
public DataTable Fresh { get {
    try {
        this.TableLib.ReadTables( ).Wait( );
        if (this.PrimaryKeyColumn != null)
            this.TableLib.Tables[TableName].Constraints.Add( "PrimaryKey",
            this.PrimaryKeyColumn.Select<string, DataColumn>( columnName => this.TableLib.Tables[TableName].Columns[columnName] ).ToArray( ),
            true );
        return this.TableLib.Tables[this.TableName];
    } catch ( Exception EX ) {
        EX.Report( );
        return null;
    }
} }

public async Task<DataTable> FreshAsync( ) {
    await this.TableLib.ReadTables( );
    if ( this.PrimaryKeyColumn != null )
        this.TableLib.Tables[TableName].Constraints.Add( "PrimaryKey",
            this.PrimaryKeyColumn.Select<string, DataColumn>( columnName => this.TableLib.Tables[TableName].Columns[columnName] ).ToArray( ),
            true );
    return this.TableLib.Tables[this.TableName];
}
```

Also; the constructor of the `SqlTableAsync` class takes a `string[ ]` with the column names on which the primary key should be based and assigns that value to the local `PrimaryKeyColumn` `string[ ]` variable. Now I am getting this new exception on the `QatiTables.Players.Fresh` property telling me that there already exists a constraint within the table that matches this constraint.

***what***

The `Fresh` method should be dumping the `DataSet DS` within the `SqlLibAsync` class when it calls the `ReadTables` method of that class, meaning that no keys should exist within the tables of that data set as it has *just been created* because the `ReadTables` method is being called ***JUST PRIOR*** to trying to assign that primary key.

I need coffee...

Comment: a well wriiten question. love it.

Comment: Looking at the dataset which throws the exception, are there any other rows with duplicate keys?

Comment: @Lathejockey81: No; The query made results in a table that has just one row, or two rows (each with the same primary key) when I'm testing. Also, the source table on the data base, when I check it, only ever has one of these rows, which makes sense because things would be pretty screwed up if it had two rows with the same primary key.

Comment: So you're saying that `QatiTables.Players.Fresh` does not contain any rows with duplicate primary keys at the point when the exception is thrown? Does anything look odd when using a breakpoint and a watcher to analyse the dataset? My initial suspicion is a `TableAdapter.Fill()` command being called twice on a single dataset.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 No, the QatiTables.Players.Fresh DOES contain duplicate rows, where it SHOULDN'T because the source table (on the database) doesn't. I tend to agree with you about the TableAdapter.Fill( ) being called twice on the same dataset. Are you able to discern how this is happening?

Comment: The first code block is using the fill command to dump all the tables into a single dataset. My first suspicion is the foreach that loops through all the adapters. Make sure the adapters collection is clean, and if it is, break after each fill to make sure it is doing what you expect.

Comment: @Lathejockey81 I will take a look at that. In this case, however, there is only a single (or rather, SHOULD be only a single) adapter within the array. I will make a check on that and report my findings but it may be a few days - I am in the middle of a system backup and format as my system is running rather sluggish.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that Single will throw an exception if any number other than one row is found. Use FirstOrDefault and do a null check
See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) link here
+1 for an extensive set of source code, nice post!

Edit:
After review one of your Single statements is out of place, check out

```
public static SqlTableAsync Players { get; }
```

It looks like that single need to take in the filter as its lambda or make that a first.

Comment: Yes, you are right about Single throwing the exception, and I understand the how and the why about it, but my problem is that the table shouldn't have 2 of these rows in it. The Single extension which filters on criteria should only be returning a single row because I'm filtering on the primary key of the table from which the DataTable is derived. That the DataTable should have two rows with the same Primary Key is incomprehensible!

Comment: Regarding the Players property: that property is specially formulated such that the query would only ever return one row on the filter (QatiTables.GameSessions.Fresh.AsEnumerable( ).Single(Row => ... ) or it would throw an exception. That .Single( ) call would result in an exception being thrown when the SqlTableAsync class was initially being called if the GameSessions table filter resulted in more than one row. This isn't happening though.

Answer (score 0):

Okay; after much wailing and gnashing of teeth, a simple change in the `ReadTables` method of the `SqlLibAsync` class has ended my problems. How and why, I do not know. I would like to leave this question open for research purposes in hopes that someone in the future can explain to me what exactly was going on and why this simple change has resolved my torturous nightmare.

```
/// <summary>
/// Asynchronously read tables for this SqlLibAsync instance.
/// </summary>
public async Task ReadTables( ) {
    //this.DS = new DataSet( ); <-----This line of code has been moved...
    using ( MySqlConnection MSQCon = new MySqlConnection( this.ConnectionString ) ) {
        await MSQCon.OpenAsync( );
        try {
            this.DS = new DataSet( ); //<-----To here. Then, abra cadabra, my problem disappeared. What is this, I don't even...
            foreach ( MySqlDataAdapter Adapter in this.Adapters ) {
                Adapter.SelectCommand.Connection = MSQCon;
                await Adapter.FillAsync( this.DS, Adapter.TableMappings.Cast<DataTableMapping>( ).First( ).SourceTable );
            }
        } catch ( Exception ex ) {
            ex.Report( );
        }
        await MSQCon.CloseAsync( );
    }
    if ( this.DS.Tables.Count == 0 )
        await this.ReadTables( );
}
```